# how to set the display of the form by pressing the button from the toolbar in Pyqt5 or PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, pyqt5

For example When I open the app to show me one form, when I click the button show second form that will contain the data entry fields

Home

[image]

Second form

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. Easiest (not cleanest) is to group the widgets in your "forms" into containers (QFrame, QGroupbox, etc) and connect the triggered signal from your actions into suitable slots that hide/show these containers. Below you can see an example (PySide) of this, on which I'm using two QFrames in order to separate your "forms". The layout behaviour can be modified easily.

The form file (compiled from the designer's ui file):

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'example.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Apr 10 13:18:07 2018
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Example(object):
    def setupUi(self, Example):
        Example.setObjectName("Example")
        Example.resize(800, 770)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(Example)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.fr_one = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.fr_one.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.fr_one.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.fr_one.setObjectName("fr_one")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.fr_one)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.bt_quit = QtGui.QPushButton(self.fr_one)
        self.bt_quit.setObjectName("bt_quit")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.bt_quit)
        self.cb_selection = QtGui.QComboBox(self.fr_one)
        self.cb_selection.setObjectName("cb_selection")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.cb_selection)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.fr_one, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.fr_two = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.fr_two.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.fr_two.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.fr_two.setObjectName("fr_two")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.fr_two)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.fr_two)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.le_fname = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.fr_two)
        self.le_fname.setObjectName("le_fname")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.le_fname)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.fr_two)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.le_sname = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.fr_two)
        self.le_sname.setObjectName("le_sname")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.le_sname)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.fr_two)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.le_address = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.fr_two)
        self.le_address.setObjectName("le_address")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.le_address)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 267, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.fr_two, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        Example.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(Example)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 47))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Example.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(Example)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Example.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(Example)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        Example.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.actionAction1 = QtGui.QAction(Example)
        self.actionAction1.setObjectName("actionAction1")
        self.actionAction2 = QtGui.QAction(Example)
        self.actionAction2.setObjectName("actionAction2")
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionAction1)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionAction2)

        self.retranslateUi(Example)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Example)

    def retranslateUi(self, Example):
        Example.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.bt_quit.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "Quit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "First name", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "Second name", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "Address", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "toolBar", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.actionAction1.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "action1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.actionAction2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Example", "action2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

The main file:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from _example import Ui_Example

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Example()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.fr_two.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.cb_selection.addItem("motif")

        # here are the connections of the corresponding actions on the QToolBar
        self.ui.actionAction1.triggered.connect(self._changeView1)
        self.ui.actionAction2.triggered.connect(self._changeView2)

    def _changeView1(self):
        # fr_one is the first frame (the one that contains the 'quit' button and the QCombobox)
        # fr_two is the second frame (the one that contains the QLineEdits)
        self.ui.fr_one.setVisible(True)
        self.ui.fr_two.setVisible(False)

    def _changeView2(self):
        self.ui.fr_one.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.fr_two.setVisible(True)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```